# Is there any UNIX V7 certified operating system?

Tags: posix, oracle

I was just having a look at [The Open Group official register of UNIX Certified Products](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/index2.html), and it doesn't list any system to be registered for the UNIX V7 brand.
Nevertheless, I did remember that Oracle Solaris [was announced to have achieved the certification](https://twitter.com/theopengroup/status/1034785507610447872):

> We are pleased to announce that Oracle Corporation has achieved certification to the UNIX V7 Product Standard for: Oracle Solaris 11.4 Operating System and later on SPARC-based and X86 based platforms
>   For more information: http://ow.ly/8fT830lBjfu #UNIX

This tweet dates back to August 2018. Still, as of now, no update has been made to the register.
Is this just due to delays and bad maintenance of the site?
Do you know any other infos regarding systems that have reached compliance for the UNIX V7 brand?

Comment: Not to be confused with good old V7 UNIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Open Brand Register [entry for Solaris](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3642.htm) can still be found on the web site, and still appears [in some search results](http://www.opengroup.org/csq/search/t=XV1.html), but presumably it hasn’t been renewed, which is [a requirement for products to continue to be listed](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/docs/UNIXV7_Certification_Guide.html#Renewals).

It did appear in the register [after the announcement](http://web.archive.org/web/20181209194642/https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/), so its absence isn’t due to a lack of updates — rather, it was added to the list, and then removed again. (This applies to a large number of certified products.)

So there is no currently-registered UNIX V7 certified operating system, but there have been in the past.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out :) Why does this happen for a large number of certified products? What could have been a reason for this case?

Comment: Their certifications aren’t renewed, but I don’t know why that is the case. I mentioned that many other products were affected because this comes up regularly in discussions of certified products — people remember that some OS was certified, go and look in the register and don’t find it, because it’s expired.

Comment: Certifications (and renewals) cost money and administrative effort, but depending on market perception may not generate sufficient additional business. In such situations, it may be economically sound to let a certification expire, but of course, it's also possible that whoever made the decision just didn't see the economic value, just the cost.

Answer (score 3):

As of 30-September-2020, [AIX version 7.2 TL5 (or later) on systems using CHRP system architecture with POWER™ processors](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3658.htm) is now the sole certified implementation of UNIX V7.

As some of the other answers mentioned, previously Oracle Solaris 11.4 was also [registered on 10-April-2018](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3642.htm), but it appears its registration as a certified UNIX V7 implementation has since been withdrawn. While there has been (to my knowledge) no public explanation of this, we can surmise that Oracle decided that it was not worth their while to pay the renewal fees.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you please run the test suite for waitid() on AIX 7? See http://sf.net/projects/schilytools/files/posix/waitid.c This did not pass with previous AIX versions...

Comment: @schily I would be happy to if I had an AIX box :) (At my previous job we did have some, at my current job we don't have any.)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Solaris 11.4 was certified for POSIX issue 7 compliance last year, it was the first and only OS to pass that certification.

Unfortunately, a few weeks ago, Oracle did withdraw it's participation on the UNIX branding campaign. This is really sad news that does not yet has been officially announced.